# Simplification of Equation Involving Second Partials

Tags: integration, physics

I was reading [this article](http://physics.unipune.ernet.in/~phyed/26.3/File4.pdf) and I'm trying to follow this author's proof. The author jumps from

$$\psi_1(x)\frac{\partial^2\psi_2(x)}{\partial x^2}-\psi_2(x)\frac{\partial^2\psi_1(x)}{\partial x^2}=0$$
to

$$\psi_1(x)\frac{\partial\psi_2(x)}{\partial x}-\psi_2(x)\frac{\partial\psi_1(x)}{\partial x}=Constant$$

I've tried integrating by parts but it just seems to get mucky fast. Can anyone help me clarify how this is such a simple procedure?

Comment: You may get further by looking up the term "first integral of motion", which is what the second line is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, let $\partial$ stand for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\partial^2$ for the iterated $\partial$. Now by the product rule run slightly in reverse

$$\psi_1 \partial^2 \psi_2 = \partial(\psi_1 \partial\psi_2) - \partial\psi_1\partial\psi_2$$

and

$$\psi_2 \partial^2 \psi_1 = \partial(\psi_2 \partial\psi_1) - \partial\psi_2\partial\psi_1$$

Finally, we have

$$\psi_1 \partial^2 \psi_2 - \psi_2 \partial^2 \psi_1  = \partial(\psi_1 \partial\psi_2) - \partial\psi_1\partial\psi_2 - (\partial(\psi_2 \partial\psi_1) - \partial\psi_2\partial\psi_1)$$

which equals

$$\partial(\psi_1 \partial\psi_2) - \partial(\psi_2\partial\psi_1) = \partial(\psi_1 \partial\psi_2-\psi_2\partial\psi_1) $$

which means that

$$\psi_1 \partial\psi_2-\psi_2\partial\psi_1 = \text{constant}$$

Comment: Thanks so much Aleks. That's a neat trick.